# MessageFilter ApproximateTime doesn't call callback function

Tags: ros, c++, ros-melodic, callback, message-filter

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I'm trying to implement MessageFilter in a class. I'm using ROS1 Melodic on Ubuntu 18.04. The code compiles without any errors but when I play my bag file, the callback function aren't called. I checked some other questions but I couldn't find a solution.
Here is my code :

Main:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include "object_localization/CloudPainter.hpp"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    ros::init(argc, argv, "cloud_painter");
    ros::NodeHandle node_handle("~");

    object_localization::CloudPainter cloud_painter(node_handle);

    ros::spin();
    return 0;
}
```

CloudPainter.hpp:

```
#pragma once

#include <ros/ros.h>

#include <message_filters/subscriber.h>
#include <message_filters/synchronizer.h>
#include <message_filters/sync_policies/approximate_time.h>

#include <sensor_msgs/PointCloud2.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/Image.h>

typedef message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2> PointCloudSubscriber;
typedef message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::Image> ImageSubscriber;
typedef message_filters::sync_policies::ApproximateTime<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2,
                                                        sensor_msgs::Image>
    MySyncPolicy;

namespace object_localization
{
class CloudPainter
{
public:
    CloudPainter(ros::NodeHandle& t_node_handle);

private:
    bool readParameters();

    void messageFilterCallback(const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2ConstPtr& t_point_cloud,
                    const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& t_image);

    ros::NodeHandle& m_node_handle;
    std::string m_lidar_topic;
    std::string m_camera_topic;
    PointCloudSubscriber m_point_cloud_subscriber;
    ImageSubscriber m_image_subscriber;
    message_filters::Synchronizer<MySyncPolicy> m_synchronizer;
};
}  // namespace object_localization
```

CloudPainter.cpp:

```
#include "object_localization/CloudPainter.hpp"

namespace object_localization
{
CloudPainter::CloudPainter(ros::NodeHandle& t_node_handle)
: m_node_handle(t_node_handle)
, m_synchronizer(MySyncPolicy(10), m_point_cloud_subscriber, m_image_subscriber)
{
    if (!readParameters())
    {
        ROS_ERROR("Could not read parameters.");
        ros::requestShutdown();
    }

    ROS_INFO("Lidar topic: : %s", m_lidar_topic.c_str());
    ROS_INFO("Camera topic: : %s", m_camera_topic.c_str());

    m_point_cloud_subscriber.subscribe(m_node_handle, m_lidar_topic,  1);
    m_image_subscriber.subscribe(m_node_handle, m_camera_topic,  1);
    m_synchronizer.registerCallback(
        boost::bind(&CloudPainter::messageFilterCallback, this, _1, _2));

    ROS_INFO("Successfully launched node.");
}

bool CloudPainter::readParameters()
{
    if (!m_node_handle.getParam("lidar_topic", m_lidar_topic))
    {
        return false;
    }
    if (!m_node_handle.getParam("camera_topic", m_camera_topic))
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

void CloudPainter::messageFilterCallback(const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2ConstPtr& t_point_cloud,
                                        const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& t_image)
{
    ROS_INFO("Callback.");
}
}  // namespace object_localization
```

Output:

```
[ INFO] [1625585829.773481527]: Lidar topic: : velodyne_points
[ INFO] [1625585829.774161339]: Camera topic: : pylon_camera_node/image_rect
[ INFO] [1625585829.777213271]: Successfully launched node.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/381890/messagefilter-approximatetime-doesn%27t-call-callback-function/) by [mebasoglu](https://answers.ros.org/users/51148/mebasoglu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2021-07-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You appear to be only passing a *private* `NodeHandle` to your `CloudPainter` ctor:

> ```
> ros::NodeHandle node_handle("~");
> ```

```
object_localization::CloudPainter cloud_painter(node_handle);
```

That's why you need to prefix your topics with `/`, otherwise `CloudPainter` will try to subscribe to `/cloud_painter/velodyone_points` and `/cloud_painter/pylon_camera_node/image_rect` which don't exist.

With the `/` prefix, the `ros::Subscriber` will consider the topic names already fully resolved, and thus will not start searching for them in the private namespace of the node.

> Ok, I found my problem. I didn't use "/" before topic names. So I changed "velodyne_points" to "/velodyne_points"

the better solution would be to either:

- use a regular `NodeHandle` for your subscriptions (ie: not a private one), or
- use [remapping](http://wiki.ros.org/Remapping%20Arguments) (and #q303611) to remap default topic names to the topics you wish to subscribe to. In your case that could be a `points` and a `image` topic, which you then remap to `/velodyone_points` and `/pylon_camera_node/image_rect` during `rosrun` or `roslaunch` of your node

  With `roslaunch`, that could look something like this:

  ```
   <launch>
     <node name="cloud_painter" type="cloud_painter" pkg="...">
       <remap from="image" to="/pylon_camera_node/image_rect" />
       <remap from="points" to="/velodyne_points" />
     </node>
   </launch>
  ```

Configuring topic names via ROS parameters is a bit of an anti-pattern (although opinions differ on that: #q342777).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-07-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mebasoglu](https://answers.ros.org/users/51148/mebasoglu/) on 2021-07-06**:
Thank you.